# Is $\epsilon$ always contained in $\Sigma^*$?

Tags: formal-languages, terminology, regular-languages

Please correct me on any terminology. For some reason I'm a bit confused.

$\Sigma = \{\epsilon, 0, 1\}$

This means my alphabet, $\Sigma$, contains three symbols ($\epsilon, 0, 1$).

$\Sigma^*$ is the language over $\Sigma$, and it equals $\{\epsilon, 0, 1, 01, 10\}$.

My regular expression for $\Sigma^*$: $\epsilon+0+1+(01)+(10)$.

First question: Does every $\Sigma^*$ include $\epsilon$? I see some with, and some without. I feel like this is a big difference because your regular expression and DFSA will be different.

Second question: At this point, I would have five accepting states in a DFSA? Since the first state is the empty string, is it $\epsilon$? Or is the first state just nothing, which transitions to a second state via $\epsilon$ which contains the empty string?

Comment: The grapheme $\epsilon$ is conventionally used by many authors as a symbol of the metalanguage they create to talk about languages formally. It denotes a string that has no symbols, so we can operate with it, indirectly. It therefore cannot be a symbol of the language that is being defined.

Comment: So $\Sigma^*$ never has $\epsilon$ in it? That would make sense since the English language wouldn't have an empty string in it.

Comment: The "$*$" in "$\Sigma^*$" is called "Kleene star", and it also has a conventional meaning that is incompatible with the use you are making of it. Any good book on formal languages will help you understand it, and rewrite your question accordingly, if still necessary.

Comment: Hmm I thought $\Sigma^*$ was the set of every possible symbol combination in $\Sigma$?

Comment: Combinations of 0 or more symbols, not limited to two (as in your example - by the way, you missed $11$, and $00$, for that matter). That means $\Sigma^*$ will necessarily include the empty word, for every alphabet $\Sigma$. Please, consider rewriting your question. It is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: My question is whether my understanding is correct. Which are lines 2-4. Then I have two additional questions. But you have corrected my third line. It should be $\Sigma^* = \{\epsilon?, 0, 00, ..., 0^n, 1, 1, 11, ..., 1^n, 01, 001, ..., 10, 110, ..., etc\}$ So $\epsilon$ should not be in there.

Comment: A general hint (that should probably be on every page of every StackExchange site): you are probably not asking a clear, answerable question if your title does not state it. At present, this title does not state a question at all.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but if I state some facts, and I want to know if they are true, then I follow up the facts with additional questions. How is it unclear? I mean, if I were to answer this question, I would copy/paste it, and make corrections. Then answer the questions.

Comment: OK, after the edit you have two clear questions that we can answer. Thanks. It would still be better to ask them separately ...

Comment: @AndréSouzaLemos do you see the text-box below, the one with the "post your answer" below it?  (;

Comment: Of course I do. What I don't see is an answerable question.

Comment: It's alright if you don't understand my question. I will ask it somewhere else. Thank you for pointing out my $\Sigma^*$ mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, $\epsilon$ stands for the empty string: the string with no characters, which would be `""` is most programming languages. It's too confusing to have $\epsilon$ be a symbol in the alphabet, so I'm going to rename it and write your alphabet as $\Sigma=\{e,0,1\}$. (The alternative would be to use some other symbol to denote the empty string.)

Now, *by definition*, $\Sigma^*$ is the set of all finite strings that can be written using the characters of $\Sigma$. This always includes the empty string $\epsilon$ and, as long as $\Sigma\neq\emptyset$, it also contains strings of all finite lengths. So the claim in the question that $\Sigma^*=\{e, 0, 1, 01, 10\}$ is incorrect: $\Sigma^*$ is an infinite set.

The regular expression for $\Sigma^*$ is $(e+0+1)^*$; the automaton consists of a single state, which is accepting and has transitions to itself for each symbol in $\Sigma$.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections. I understand where my confusion is coming from now. One last question, is the first state of a DFSA always epsilon?

Comment: @fossdeep "Is the first state of a DFSA always epsilon?" That doesn't make sense: it doesn't type-check, so to speak. The first state is a state; $\epsilon$ is a string. After reading $\epsilon$ (i.e., before it's read any actual characters), the automaton is always in its initial state. However, it may return to the initial state after it's read some nonzero number of characters.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the easy answer. It attempts to explain in detail the source of the
confusion. With apologies as it makes also for a very long answer.

Your confusion is related to an issue that is both essential and often
glossed over, the **distinction between syntax and semantics**.
It is often the source of confusion in some formal issues.

In any discourse, these two aspects are always both present, but often not
cerefully distinguished, though there are notations to do so in
writing, but not so much in speech.

Typically, to make the distinction clear, a dog may bite you (not
mine), but the word "dog" does not bite and is the syntactic
representation of the concept of dog, or possibly of a specific dog.

You always have a syntactic discourse (what gets spoken or written),
but it is always intended to stand for semantics concepts, to
represent them. When you say: "I am hungry", you utter three words
meaning to convey the idea that you feel like eating something.
Alternatively you could say it in German: "Ich bin hungrig" , or in
French: "j'ai faim", with a different syntactic representation, but
with the same meaning, i.e. the same semantics. Note that, in writteh
form at least, the syntactic representation is always a sequence of
characters, all belonging to the Latin Alphabet in this case, which is
a collections of representation symbols.

Similarly, the same number can be represented syntactically by "7" in
decimal notation, by "VII" in Roman numerals, by "111"in binary
positional nottion, by "lllllll" in unary notation, by "seven"in
English, etc. An important remark is that the choice of notation can
make you life and your communication easier or harder, exactly like the
proper choice of representing data structure in algorithm design
(these are closely related problems).

The difficulty of formal languages is that they are used to study
syntax. Thus formal syntax becomes the semantic part of the discourse,
and you need a syntax to represent it. And this can become very
confusing.

To discuss about syntax, as the semantic topic of the discussion, you
first define an alphabet. To remain abstract, we give it a
mathematical name which could be anything, but we often choose the
name $\Sigma$. Of course, we have to know the symbols in that
alphabet (like letters in the Latin alphabet), so we define the set of symbols that compose it, by writing:
$\Sigma=\{a,b,4,5,\eta,+\}$ if these are the 6 symbols we want to use.

Note that this notation is probably an abuse. If you really want to
talk about these symbols, they should be written between quotes, for
example as '$a$', '$b$', '$4$', etc. to distinguish the symbol as
semantic object from the syntactic representation used to talk about
it, exactly as I did above to explain that the word "dog" never bites.

But this would be tedious and awkward to write and read, so that there
is an unsaid convention that, unless it is necessary for better
understanding, the symbols are allowed not to be quoted and to stand
for themselves as semantic objects.

Now symbols can be concatenated into strings. The word "dog" is
typically a string of 3 letters (letteres being symbols). Strings can
have any finite length, i.e. any number of symbols, including
zero. They are often represented by the sequence of symbols composing
the string, surrounded by double quotes. An English written word is a
string of letter, and that is why I wrote "dog" thus to mean the
string that represent a dog. Of course, the string of length 0,
containing no symbol, is then represented by "", with nothing between
te quotes.

Note that, in strict mathematical sense, a string of length 1 may have
to be distinguished from the character that composes that
string. Hence the notation differ, with single or double quotes. But
that is not always respected, assuming for example that context will
tell which is intended.

When talking of syntax, the convention of having symbols stand for
themselves is often extended to strings, which get written without
quotes, though othen with a different font (italics), which is similar
to quoting. It is usually easy to read, except for the empty string
which becomes invisible if it is to stand for itself, without external
markers.

Hence, the solution is to use a special syntactic representation for
the empty string, to give it a name. This name is often, in
mathematical text, the Greek letter $\epsilon$, or sometimes the Greek
letter $\lambda$.

If the alphabet is noted $\Sigma$, then $\Sigma^*$ represents (is the
syntactic representation for) the set of all finite strings composed of symbols
of $\Sigma$, including the empty string, however represented. There is
no upper limit to the length of these string (but they are all
finite), so that their number is infinite. In the case of your
example, it is any finite sequence of $0$ and $1$ in any order.

In your question, you represent strings as standing for themselves,
without quotes, so the representation for the empty string is
naturally $\epsilon$. Hence, you *always* have $\epsilon\in\Sigma^*$,
independently of the symbols that $\Sigma$ contains.

But if you write $\Sigma=\{\epsilon,0,1\}$, you are saying that you
have an alphabet with three symbols, '$\epsilon$', '$0$', and '$1$',
precisely as you say in your question.  But then, of course, the
symbol $\epsilon$ stands for itself, and can no longer be used to
represent the empty string.

This creates a lot of confusion for readers, since they are used to
see it as standing for the empty string. So it should be avoided.

When $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$, the regular expression for $\Sigma^*$ is
$\Sigma^*=(0+1)^*$. Basically, it is the Kleene star closure operator
applied to the set of all strings of length 1 on alphabet $\Sigma$.

The corresponding minimal deterministic finite state automaton (DFA)
has only one state $q$, and a transition from that state to itself for
any symbol in $\Sigma$. The state $q$ is bot initial state and final
accepting state. Since the initial state is an accepting state, it
does not need to read any symbol to recognize the input. Thus it can
recongnize an empty input, i.e. $\epsilon$. Any DFA that recognizes a
language containing the empty string $\epsilon$ must have an initial
state that is also an accepting state.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying about $\epsilon$. If $\epsilon$ was universally accepted as the empty string, then it would be fine to include it in both $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma^*$, but since it's not, it should be avoided? Or, even though it's universally accepted, it should still be avoided?

Comment: No. I am saying that any symbol that is included in Σ will stand for itself as a symbol, and thus can no longer be used to represent anything but itself. In particular it cannot be used to represent the empty string. A more subtle point is that no symbol can be accepted as universally representing a given meaning, because there are always situations when the symbols has to be used to represent something else, for exemple because of some self-referencing circularity on the concerned mathematics. BUt do not try to follow that last statement.